# Type 'TableViewAdsViewController' does not conform to protocol FBNativeAdsManagerDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-audience-network

I have an Xcode project, using the latest version of Xcode(8.2.1) and Swift(3.0.2).

I'm attempting to implement FBNativeAdsManager, along with it's delegate FBNativeAdsManagerDelegate in my project. The issue is that whenever I extend my view controller and implement the required FBNativeAdsManagerDelegate functions, Xcode errors out with:

> Type 'TableViewAdsViewController' does not conform to protocol FBNativeAdsManagerDelegate

I have searched online but I can find no particular reason for this, and I cannot reproduce it on a new project which is odd.

Please help!

[image]

Comment: Click the stop sign and let it stub out the method for you, your signature is probably wrong.

Comment: @dan Already tried that, the error still persists.

Comment: add required delegates to your class:     **public func nativeAdsLoaded() { }**

    **public func nativeAdsFailedToLoadWithError(_ error: Error) { }**

Comment: @LijithVipin That's essentially what is in the screen shot above. Adding the public keyword does nothing to change the error.

Comment: @B.N "does not conform to protocol" is shown when if your not include the required DataSource methods in to your class

Comment: @B.N FBNativeAdsManagerDelegate having 2 datasource methods ie, **func nativeAdsLoaded() { }, func nativeAdsFailedToLoadWithError(_ error: Error) { }**

Comment: @LijithVipin Both of those methods are included as shown on the screenshot on the original post, but even though they are included I still get the error. That is the main reason I have posted this question.